# railsで複数DBを素早く切り替えるためには?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

環境: ruby2.1.3, rails4.2, activerecord-sqlserver-adapter4.1

20個ほどあるデータベースを、あちこち切り替えながら処理しなくてはならない場合。
まず接続情報を格納した配列(specs)を用意して、

```
Benchmark.bm do |x|
  100.times{ x.report{ ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(specs.sample) } }
end
```

と確認してみたところ。どうにも0.9秒～1.2秒かかっているようです。
単体コストはともかくとして、最初にガッツリ全部の接続先をキープして、
クエリを投げる先だけ変えるような感じで切替コストを下げることは、できないものでしょうか。

以下、考え事：
(接続モデルをDB分作って、各モデルが継承という手も考えたのですが。全てのモデルファイルのコピーを20個ずつ作るのもおかしな話に感じます。動的にモデルを複製して継承しなおすという事も考えたのですが最後の手段にしたいなぁと)

Answer (score 1):

僕自身は実際にやったことはないですし、ご質問の状況と異なる部分もありますが、このページの内容が結構近いんじゃないかと思いました。

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16775795/rails-switch-connection-on-each-request-but-keep-a-connection-pool

上の記事から引用したコード

```
# A model class that connects to a different DB depending on the subdomain 
# we're in
class ModelBase < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true
  self.connection_handler = CustomConnectionHandler.new
end

# ...

class CustomConnectionHandler < ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::ConnectionHandler
  def initialize
    super
    @pools_by_subdomain = {}
  end

  # Override the behaviour of ActiveRecord's ConnectionHandler to return a
  # connection pool for the current domain.
  def retrieve_connection_pool(klass)
    # Get current subdomain somehow (Maybe store it in a class variable on 
    # each request or whatever)
    subdomain = @@subdomain
    @pools_by_subdomain[subdomain] ||= create_pool(subdomain)
  end

  private
  def create_pool(subdomain)
    conf = Rails.configuration.database_configuration[Rails.env].dup
    # The name of the DB for that subdomain...
    conf.update!('database' => "db_#{subdomain}")
    resolver = ActiveRecord::Base::ConnectionSpecification::Resolver.new(conf, nil)
    # Call ConnectionHandler#establish_connection, which receives a key 
    # (in this case the subdomain) for the new connection pool
    establish_connection(subdomain, resolver.spec)
  end
end
```

元記事ではサブドメインに応じてコネクションを変えるという要件になっていて、`retrieve_connection_pool`メソッドの中でコネクションを切り替えています。

このあたりをご自身の要件に合うように変更すれば、目的が達成できるかもしれません。

以上、ご参考までに。

Comment: 多忙で少々試せるまでに時間掛かっておりますが。確認してみます。